# rails - no 'before_validation' callback when importing a CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, callback

When creating a 'product', Im using a 'before_validation' callback so that additonal fields are created. For example,

```
before_validation(:on => :create) do
   self.product_name = product_title+"_"+product_type
end
```

This is great except when I want to import files through CSV.  The CSV file will already have the 'product_name' so there is no need to create it with a callback.

I dont want to use the 'before_validation' callback when importing a CSV file.

Is there a way to check and see if a CSV file exists before I create the product? Something like this

```
if csv.blank?
  before_validation(:on => :create) do
     self.product_name = product_title+" | "+product_type
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this double pipe equal to in your original `before_validation`

```
self.product_name ||= product_title+"_"+product_type
```

Will return itself if it already exists.

Comment: Thanks Billy.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Do it only if the product name is not populated already

```
before_validation(:on => :create) do
  self.product_name ||= product_title+" | "+product_type
end
```

Comment: Thanks Vimsha.  Billy said the same thing.